# How to remove curly braces from HTTP response in JavaScript when rendering on the page?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, http

When I render a HTTP response on the page using JavaScript, it is displaying the message like so:

`{"Result":"SUCCESS"}` with curly braces.

How can I render a response message on the page without having the curly braces?

This is what I have done:

```
        function processRequest(e) {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                $("#content").text((JSON.stringify(response)));
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to parse json the response text and after that just use like this to get the content

```
 $("#content").text(response.Result);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the other responses in my code. I have now included them because when I try using this suggestion, it only works for the 200 response code. The 400 and 500 response messages do not render for some reason...

Comment: Did you check the response text when xhr status is 400 or 500.

Comment: Oops, my bad! Thank you for this! Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#content').text(response['Result']);
```

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ this is nothing but above answer. while I am typing my answer above one is posted. :(

Comment: It is not because the other answer describes the solution that it dispenses you from explaining yours.

Comment: .parse() to convert an string to json object but .stringify() to convert json obj to string. Because he want to print the message, he dosen't want to convert it to a string. just read the property. thats all